# Create trigger in nestjs using typeorm?

Tags: triggers, nestjs, typeorm

How can I add trigger in enrollment entity which will update the corresponding course's totalEnrollment count by one for each insertion of enrollment of that course?
This is my EnrollmentEntity:

```
export class EnrollmentEntity extends CustomBaseEntity {
  
  @ManyToOne(() => CourseEntity, (courseEntity) => courseEntity.enrollments, {
    nullable: false,
  })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'course_id' })
  course: CourseEntity;

  }
```

This is my CourseEntity:

```
export class CourseEntity extends CustomBaseEntity {
  
  @Column({
    name: 'total_enrollments',
    type: 'bigint',
    nullable: false,
    default: 0,
  })
  totalEnrollments: number;

  @OneToMany(
    () => EnrollmentEntity,
    (enrollmentEntity) => enrollmentEntity.course,
  )
  enrollments: EnrollmentEntity[];
}
```

Comment: Generally you're better off just _counting_ the number of enrollments you have when you need that value rather than persisting it.

Answer (score 1):

I need to increment the totalEnrollments if any enrollment occurs. So this is how I did it.

```
export class EnrollmentEntity extends CustomBaseEntity {
      
      @ManyToOne(() => CourseEntity, (courseEntity) => courseEntity.enrollments, {
        nullable: false,
      })
      @JoinColumn({ name: 'course_id' })
      course: CourseEntity;
    
      @AfterInsert()
      async updateCourse() {
        let id = this?.course;
        const course = await CourseEntity.findOne({
            where: {
                id: String(id),
                ...isActive
            }
        });
        if (course) {
          course.totalEnrollments = Number(course?.totalEnrollments) + 1;
          await CourseEntity.save(course);
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Is this a solution to your question? If so please add aan explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@AfterInsert()` decorators, but that is not a database trigger. To create a database trigger you will have to create an empty migration and write the SQL code yourself. As far as I know, there is no way to generate SQL migration that will have all the needed code.

Please refer to this issue: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1082

It has the samples of code needed to create the trigger "manually" (write migration to create one)

Answer (score 0):

1. create empty migration by run this command `yarn migration:create ./path_to_your_migrations_folder`
2. and write trigger like this below code: `! DON'T TEST ON PROD !`

```
import { MigrationInterface, QueryRunner } from 'typeorm';
export class TriggerForCourseInInserOnEnrollment703851693932
  implements MigrationInterface
{
  public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.query(`
                    CREATE TRIGGER update_Course_totalEnrollment_on_insert
                    AFTER INSERT ON enrollment
                    FOR EACH ROW
                    BEGIN
                        UPDATE course
                        SET totalEnrollment = totalEnrollment + 1
                        WHERE id = NEW.courseId; // this is foreign key, enrollment connected with master table(course table)
                    END;
                `);
  }

  public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    await queryRunner.query(
      `DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS update_Course_totalEnrollment_on_insert`,
    );
  }
}
```

3. Finally run migration by run this command `yarn migration:run`

**Bonus:**

1. Using an `update on insert` trigger can also be beneficial when paired with an `update on delete` trigger.

```
import { MigrationInterface, QueryRunner } from 'typeorm';
export class TriggerForCourseInDeleteOnEnrollment703851693932
  implements MigrationInterface
{
  public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.query(`
                    CREATE TRIGGER update_Course_totalEnrollment_on_delete
                    AFTER DELETE ON enrollment
                    FOR EACH ROW
                    BEGIN
                        UPDATE course
                        SET totalEnrollment = totalEnrollment - 1
                        WHERE id = OLD.courseId; // this is foreign key, enrollment connected with master table(course table)
                    END;
                `);
  }

  public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    await queryRunner.query(
      `DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS update_Course_totalEnrollment_on_delete`,
    );
  }
}
```